# How does one find the name to a mathematical concept that they have a definition of?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

In particular, I was trying to figure out if there was an already established name for what I have eventually found referred to as *homogeneous* structures (structures such that for any two $x$, $y$ in that structure, there is an automorphism bringing $x$ to $y$).

What I'm wondering is if there was some way to cut down the amount of time I spent looking for the name of the definition. Is there some easy way to find what a specific concept is called?

**EDIT:** Yeah I didn't know about the terminology tag. Problem essentially solved. But, if anybody else has other ideas, those would still be cool too!

Comment: If Googling a description of the concept (or some set of keywords) does not turn up stuff, you could always ask here with the [terminology] tag.

Comment: @angryavian Oh! That is exactly what I needed. Thanks!